# Pillow is installed, but still getting "ImportError: No module named PIL"

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I did find this question asked by few more people, but none of those exactly met my situation, so asking here myself.
I've (rather had) two versions of Python (2.7 and 3.4.3) on my Mac running the latest MacOS High Sierra. As I understand, the v2.7 comes as default installation with the MacOS. And I installed the 3.4.3 (from .dmg file downloaded from the python site). Thus now, the python command defaults to the 2.7, while python3 points to the 3.4.3 in the terminal.
While trying to learn, I tried a python script that uses

`import PIL` and `from PIL import Image`

But when running, this gave the error `ImportError: No module named PIL`.
Upon research on google, I figured out to install PIL and Pillow using

`sudo pip install Pillow`

It installed correctly, but I'm still getting the same error.
To remove the confusion, I decided to remove the python 3.4.3 from the system. But even after it's removed, I still get the same error.
Even `pip list` displays `Pillow 5.1.0` alright.
So right now, I've only Python 2.7, and the error persists, while Pillow is also in there.

`which python` gives `/opt/local/bin/python` as the path.

Does any of the above ring a bell? Any ideas, what else could be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Phew, finally found the issue. Thanks @Yash for the pointers.
Incidentally I did a `which -a python` and surprisingly got this output:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Damn, I don't remember when I installed a second 2.7 version on the `/opt/local/bin` folder (probably via macports). Alright, removed the confusion, deleted this python, so now I'm left only with the system installed python at `/usr/bin`.
And now the imports all run perfectly fine as expected. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sudo pip install image
```

I hope it works! One more thing, do check if you're running python3 filename.py instead of python filename.py, if you want to install it for Python 3, run the command,

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try to install image, I get this output: `Requirement already satisfied...` with image 1.5.22, django 1.11.13, pillow 5.1.0 and pytz 2013.7

Comment: Did you get your desired output?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the status quo. Could it be something to do with paths of Python? Can you point me to the folder/file to check?

Comment: Yes, I feel the same. DO you have your Python installed via Conda?

Comment: I would suggest also suggest you to install Python3 and then run command sudo pip3 install Pillow and then in command line interpreter of Python 3, run import PIL.

Comment: No, the python I have now is only 2.7 that comes default with MacOS. I've removed python 3 already.

Comment: Another thing I just discovered. In Python, I typed `help()` and then `modules` to see the list of modules, and I really couldn't see either pip, PIL, Image, or Pillow listed among the modules that showed up. Somewhere my python is not able to read these modules, even though they're installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the PATH. I also think that the python packages aren't installed with your default Python. Do you have Conda or Anaconda installed? If yes, try to install the package by using conda command and then try to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Installation:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Windows Installation:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pillow
```

If you get something like access denied error run the below command

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pillow --user
```